# Animação transform scale "borrando" svg enquanto anima

Tags: css, svg, webkit, transform

Estou com um problema para fazer uma animação onde tenho um `circle` em `svg` e preciso fazê-lo aumentar até cobrir toda a tela, como um `FAB` que se transforma em uma div, já fiz uma animação dessa porém com muita gambiarra de `background-size` e `background-position`.

O modo mais simples e que tem melhor performance foi usando o `transform: scale();`, ficou de jeito que eu queria mas aí vem o problema, no Firefox funcionou perfeitamente, porém no Chrome (e no Opera que estou utilizando) o svg fica 'borrado' por assim se dizer enquanto está ocorrendo o `scale`.
Tem algum modo de corrigir isso nem que tenha que usar alguma biblioteca js ou algo do tipo, pois já tentei de tudo o que eu sei e nada adiantou. Segue o código que estou usando.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function () {
        svg = $(this);
        if(svg.attr("class") == "btn active") {
            svg.attr("class", "btn");
        }
        else {
            svg.attr("class", "btn active");
        }
  });
})
```

```css
.btn {
            fill: #1dc7ff;
            width: 3.5rem;
            height: 3.5rem;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: fixed;
            right: 1rem;
            bottom: 1rem;
            transition: .05s;
        }
        .btn:active {
            transform: scale(.95);
            transition: 4s;
        }
        .btn.active {
            transform: scale(100);
            transition: 10s;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg class="btn">
    <circle cx="1.75rem" cy="1.75rem" r="1.75rem"></circle>
</svg>
```

**Obs:** já tentei usar o código abaixo que encontrei em vários fóruns mas não resolveu:

```
svg {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Imagem de como fica durante a animação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que depende do browser. Em qual você está testando? Pelo menos no Chrome/OSX não vejo muito problema na animação. Ela é um pouco rápida, talvez isso seja a causa do borrão?

Comment: Pronto editei a velocidade

Comment: Sei que fica assim somente no Chrome e Opera, mas como são navegadores muito utilizados (jugo o Chrome) preciso resolver isso.

Comment: kk o problema não é a velocidade da animação e sim o modo como o `svg` fica borrado durante a animação `scale` como deixei o exemplo na imagem.

Comment: Acho que o que vc tinha que fazer era o contrário: criar um svg gigante e colocar ele inicialmente menor. Assim não iria estourar. O que vc tha fazendo é criando um pequeno e aumentando... o navegador estoura ele quando aumenta.

Comment: Tudo bem @DvD já vi algo assim em um fórum em inglês mas não consegui entender, poderia fazer um exemplo

Comment: Blz @DvD sua sugestão deu certo, coloque um exemplo para que eu de como respondida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguns navegadores "estouram" a qualidade do `svg` quando aumentado seu tamanho original (ex, Chrome).

Uma solução é criar um `svg` com tamanho original igual à maior escala que você queria e reduzi-lo inicialmente com o `scale`. Assim ao ser clicado, ele iria crescer até o tamanho original, sem perda de qualidade.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function () {
        svg = $(this);
        if(svg.attr("class") == "btn active") {
            svg.attr("class", "btn");
        }
        else {
            svg.attr("class", "btn active");
        }
  });
})
```

```css
.btn {
            fill: #1dc7ff;
            width: 80rem;
            height: 80rem;
            border-radius: 50%;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: fixed;
            right: -30rem;
            bottom: -37rem;
            transition: .05s;
            transform: scale(.01);
        }
        .btn:active {
            transform: scale(.95);
            transition: 4s;
        }
        .btn.active {
            transform: scale(100);
            transition: 100s;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="btn">
    <circle cx="40rem" cy="40rem" r="40rem"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Caso alguém esteja com dificuldades em fazer a animação deixo um exemplo com algumas modificações pequenas para funcionar como eu queria, mas sem a resposta do @DvD não teria dado certo. Usei duas bibliotecas o Jquery e TweenMax GSAP, poré ela resolvia parcialmente meu problema e com a solução da resposta acima consegui fazer. segue link https://jsfiddle.net/wvo67yc2/